# SignalR - Private Messaging-Userid

Tags: jquery, asp.net, signalr, chat, private-messaging

I am working on Signal-R private messaging. I tried to use sessions but didn't do. I want to use user-ids from database instead of context.ConnectionId. How can i do this?

Comment: you can pass a userId (or any sort of information) from the client on hub connection as a parameter, and then estabilish a 1:1 group in your hub. You can then execute hub methods which target that group (with one ID) which will essentially accomplish this

Comment: could you give me some example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use an `IUserIdProvider`. The default one generates user names from the client's `IPrincipal.Identity.Name`, but you can provide your own:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections#IUserIdProvider

This allows you to send messages using `.User(userName)` instead of `.Client(connectionId)`.

The article I linked to also provides a few alternatives such as single-user groups for messaging users without using their connection ID.